# How to get session from PHP into AngularJS for redirect

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I try to made a login system but I want the session can be taken from PHP code. If session login is `false` or `null` it will redirect to login page.
Here my run AngularJS code :

```
app.run(["$rootScope", 'adminService', '$location', function($rootScope, adminService, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function() {
        $location.path('/login');
    });
}]);
```

Routing code :

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
    }).when('/administrator', {
        templateUrl: './part/administrator.html',
        controller: 'adminPageControl'
    }).when('/administrator/:id_admin', {
        templateUrl: './part/addit-administrator.html',
    }).when('/alternatif', {
        templateUrl: './part/alternatif.html',
        controller: 'alternatifPageControl'
    }).when('/alternatif/:id_alternatif', {
        templateUrl: './part/addit-alternatif.html'
    }).when('/skala', {
        templateUrl: './part/skala.html',
        controller: 'skalaPageControl'
    }).when('/skala/:id_skala', {
        templateUrl: './part/addit-skala.html'
    }).when('/kriteria', {
        templateUrl: './part/kriteria.html',
        controller: 'kriteriaPageControl'
    }).when('/kriteria/:id_kriteria', {
        templateUrl: './part/addit-kriteria.html'
    }).when('/klasifikasi', {
        templateUrl: './part/klasifikasi.html',
        controller: 'klasifikasiPageControl'
    }).when('/klasifikasi/:id_klasifikasi', {
        templateUrl: './part/addit-klasifikasi.html'
    }).when('/analisis', {
        templateUrl: './part/topsis.php',
        controller: 'analisisPageControl'
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl: './login.html'
    }).when('/logout', {
        template: 'logout'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

PHP function session code :

```
function logincheck(){
    return $_SESSION['authid'];
}

logincheck();
```

Comment: You should create an unique session token in your backend without parsing the PHP-Session states directly into your client. Remember, AngularJS is made for SPA. So make your client communicate with backend by using an API. For example a RESTful API. Once the user logged in via the client, return a unique session token to the client. Put and validate this token on any secured data HTTP-Request. Take a look at oAuth handling, its the same.

Comment: how to make a token?

Comment: For example `$token = md5('what-ever-you-want');`

Comment: i see, thanks Lin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is right. It's a good practice to communicate with backend by using an API, because AngularJS is made for SPA. However if you insist on using session, it's ok. You can create a router such as `/api/logincheck`

PHP:

```
public function index()
{
    $res = ['login'=>false];
    if(isset($_SESSION['authid']))
    {
        $res['login'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

JS:

```
$http.get('http://XX/api/checklogin').success(function(res){
    if(res.login)
    {
        #handle it
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an unique session token in your backend without parsing the PHP-Session states directly into your client. Remember, AngularJS is made for SPA. So make your client communicate with backend by using an API. For example a [RESTful API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Once the user logged in via the client, return a unique session token to the client. Put and validate this token on every secured data HTTP-Request. Take a look at **oAuth handling**, its the same.

You could create a token simply like: `$token = md5('what-ever-you-want');` and implement it into your API logic. Here you will find more information about [handling security interfaces](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3).

[image]